# How to compare long doubles with qsort and with regard to NaN?

Tags: c, qsort

> How to compare long doubles with `qsort()` and with regard to [not-a-number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN)?

When sorting an array that might contain not-a-numbers, I would like to put all the those `NAN` to one end of the sorted array.

---

`qsort()` imposes some restriction on the compare function.

> The function shall return an integer less than, equal to, or
>   greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.
>   C11dr §7.22.5.2 3
>
> When the same objects ... are passed more than once to the comparison function, the results shall be consistent with one another. That is, for `qsort` they shall define a **total ordering** on the array, ... the same object shall always compare the same way with the key.
>   §7.22.5 4

`a > b` is false when `a <= b` or if `a` is not-a-number or if `b` is not-a-number.  So `a > b` is not the same as `!(a <= b)` as they have opposite results if one of them is NaN.

If the compare function uses `return (a > b) - (a < b);`, code would return 0 if one or both  `a` or `b` are NaN.  The array would not sort as desired and it loses the *total ordering* requirement.

The **`long double`** aspect of this sort is important when using the classify functions like `int isnan(real-floating x);` or `int isfinite(real-floating x);`.  I know `isfinite( finite_long_double_more_than_DBL_MAX)` might return false.  So I have concerns about what `isnan(some_long_double)` might do *something* unexpected.

---

I tried the below.  It apparently sorts as desired.

**Sub-question:** Is `compare()` below sufficient to sort as desired?   Any recommended simplifications?  If not - how to fix?
(For this task, it is OK for values like 0.0L and -0.0L to sort in any way)

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <float.h>

int compare(const void *a, const void *b) {
  const long double *fa = (const long double *) a;
  const long double *fb = (const long double *) b;
  if (*fa > *fb) return 1;
  if (*fa < *fb) return -1;

  if (*fa == *fb) {
    //return -memcmp(fa, fb, sizeof *fa); if -0.0, 0.0 order important.
    return 0;
  }
  // At least one of *fa or *fb is NaN
  // is *fa a non-NaN?
  if (!isnan(*fa)) return -1;
  if (!isnan(*fb)) return 1;

  // both NaN
  return 0;
  // return -memcmp(fa, fb, tbd size); if NaN order important.
}

int main(void) {
  long double x[] = { 0.0L / 0.0, 0.0L / 0.0, 0.0, 1.0L / 0.0, -0.0, LDBL_MIN,
      LDBL_MAX, 42.0, -1.0L / 0.0, 867-5309, -0.0 };
  x[0] = -x[0];
  printf("unsorted: ");
  size_t n = sizeof x / sizeof x[0];
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("%.3Le,", x[i]);
  }
  printf("\nsorted: ");
  qsort(x, n, sizeof x[0], compare);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("%.3Le,", x[i]);
  }
  puts("");
}
```

Output

```
unsorted: nan,-nan,0.000e+00,inf,-0.000e+00,3.362e-4932,1.190e+4932,4.200e+01,-inf,-4.442e+03,-0.000e+00,
sorted: -inf,-4.442e+03,-0.000e+00,0.000e+00,-0.000e+00,3.362e-4932,4.200e+01,1.190e+4932,inf,nan,-nan,
```

If I knew the compare function was correct, I'd post on Code Review for improvement ideas.  Yet I am not confident enough that code works correctly with those pesky NaNs.

Comment: Check the numbers for NaN-ness; if one is NaN and the other isn't, report that the NaN is smaller (or larger, depending on sort direction and where you want the NaNs to appear).  Presumably, if they're both NaN, return 0.  Otherwise, neither is a NaN and you process them with suitable comparisons.  If you think that there are different values within the NaNs, then you'll have to characterize the NaNs and produce a valid  
comparison according to your chosen rules.  Note that the checks for NaN-ness should probably come first, not last.

Comment: Ugh - that code is checking directly for equality on a floating point number.  Depending on what is passed in, this could lead to "interesting" results for numbers that are supposedly equal, but can't be represented the same exact value.  Beware.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: I think you're either mistaken or misstating things if you think that two "supposedly equal" numbers "can't be represented the same".

Comment: I see equality check on floating point and my eyebrows go up.  Depending on how the sort is used, it might be fine, it might not.  That was my concern.

Comment: @EOF For the purpose of this code, 2 different NaN can compare equal - they will just appear in the sorted list next to each other in some order.  Returning 0 does not violate the §7.22.5 4.

Comment: If you need a total ordering on NaNs, just use `memcmp`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler "Check the numbers for NaN-ness;" Yes, how do you recommend to do that?  `x == x`? or `isnan(some_long_double)`.  Are there any non-well known gotcha's doing either?

Comment: @R.. total ordering on NaNs,with `memcmp` seems reasonable yet with a 80-bit `long double` using a 12 or 16 byte memory, I should get stable results, but unclear on order or if some other issues occurs because of the padding.  Perhaps using `10` and not `sizeof *x` in that case is sufficient ?

Comment: @chux: I'd use `isnan()`, but my requirements are not so exacting as to want to recognize different types of NaN.  I know of signalling and non-signalling NaNs; I believe that there are numerous bit-patterns which represent a NaN. But I've never needed to study them in sufficient detail to know what's what under the `isnan()` surface. One item that's key is that if you have two elements in the array -- say `x[10]` and `x[30]` -- then comparing `x[10]` and `x[30]` should produce consistent results with comparing `x[30]` and `x[10]`. If one's negative, the other must be positive, or both zero.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes that last part is most important  [If one is negative, the (other) must be positive, or both zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48069404/how-to-compare-long-doubles-with-qsort-and-with-regard-to-nan?noredirect=1#comment83112749_48069404).  For this case the order of NaN is not important other than they are at the end of the sorted array - which simplifies the code.  Ordering `NaN` seems to only be reasonable with `memcmp()`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: In IEEE 754 binary floating-point, one the maximum value of the exponent field is assigned for infinities and NaNs. If the significand field is all zeros, it is ±∞. Otherwise, it is a NaN. So the number of NaNs equals the number of possible sign and significand field values minus two.

Comment: Both my clang and gcc don't print the minus in `-nan` as shown in the current input and output. Should I be worried about that?

Comment: Why not remove the NaNs from the array before sorting?    Even if you can sort in the presence of NaNs, any subsequent code will need to deal with their presence somehow anyway - and the options are not much more than ignore, discard, or complain.     Removing the NaNs allows subsequent code to assume they're not present i.e. less need for checks.

Comment: @usr2564301: The fact that your C implementation does not print the sign of a NaN is not something to be concerned about.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: thanks.  Wikipedia on [IEEE 754](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) and [NaN](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) explained more than I needed to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just a simple reordering of your tests, but it makes the status of `NaN` more clear if you will.

```
int compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const long double fa = *(const long double *) a;
    const long double fb = *(const long double *) b;

    if (isnan(fa))
    {
        if (isnan(fb))
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }
    if (isnan(fb))
    {
        return -1;
    }
    if (fa > fb) return 1;
    if (fa < fb) return -1;

    /* no more comparisons needed */
    return 0;
}
```

As the tests for `NaN` are at the top and no NaNs should pass through, the bottom three lines can safely be replaced with your

```
return (a > b) - (a < b);
```

Apart from the discussion of the different *types* of `NaN` (a bit sounding like how many angels can dance on a CPU core), this ought to be stable enough for your purposes, and I can't see any possible issues with this code.

With Clang, neither `-ffast-math` nor `-fdenormal-fp-math=[ieee|preserve-sign|positive-zero]` yields other results. Nor did gcc with  `-ffast-math`,
`-funsafe-math-optimizations`, and even `-ffinite-math-only` (the latter most likely because there are no operations other than a straight compare to `NaN`).

Just to be complete, I tested with both `std::numeric_limits<double>::signaling_NaN();` and `std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();` (from C++ `<limits.h>`) as well – again, no difference in the sort order.

Comment: This may make the status of NaN more clear, yet what functional differences to you see with this and the original `compare()`- if any?  Testing NaN first appears slower with typical data sets where NaN are rare. So is the only advantage code clarity?

Comment: @chux: you are questioning if your routine sorts correctly. This code uses another ordering of the tests, which *could* have led to a different result. As it does not, it appears to answer your question "is [my] `compare()` sufficient .." (with "yes" ). So, nothing to fix and little room left for simplification. (I consider reordering the tests thusly is more readable, but there are no side effects and I assume there are no, or only minor, computational benefits.)

Comment: On putting the `isNaN` test first: this is to clear any lingering doubts regarding *possibly* undefined behavior. This way, either `NaN` gets culled out first. A small note: each of these tests gets compiled to a single `fucomi` instruction. No idea if that could cause a significant slowdown (what with pipelining and all – really, no idea).

Comment: It was the good answer and the strength of the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48069404/how-to-compare-long-doubles-with-qsort-and-with-regard-to-nan/48086996#comment83136956_48069558) that led to accepting this answer.

Comment: @chux: cheerio, mate! I had some doubts on answering your *highly* technical question, especially after following the comments (worthy of preserving). And thanks back for grilling me on my answer, it was a pleasure!

Answer (score 2):

**The [NaN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) test**

```
int isnan(real-floating x);
```

> The `isnan` macro determines whether its argument value is a NaN. First, an argument represented in a format wider than its semantic type is converted to its semantic type. Then determination is based on the type of the argument.<sup>235</sup>
>   <sup>235</sup> For the `isnan` macro, the type for determination does not matter unless the implementation supports NaNs in the evaluation type but not in the semantic type.

`isnan(some_long_double)` will work as hoped except on a rare platform.

`int isunordered(real-floating x, real-floating y)` acts like `isnan()` expect it accounts for both arguments.

On *many* platforms, code could use `(a == a)` as a candidate NaN test as that evaluates to `0` when `a` is NaN and `1` otherwise.  Unfortunately, unless an implementation defines `__STDC_IEC_559__`, that is not certain to work.

---

**The compare**
**`>=, >, <, <=`** and C11 7.12.14 Comparison macros

Using `>=, >, <, <=` when at least one operand is a NaN can result in a "invalid" floating-point exception.  So prior testing for `NaN` is prudent as answered by [@usr2564301](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48069558/2410359)

C offers macros `isgreaterequal(), isgreaterequal(), isless(), islessthna()` which do the compare and not raise the "invalid" floating-point
exception.  This is good alternative for `double`, yet the macros use a *real-floating* which may differ from `long double`.  `isgreater(long_double_a, long_double_a)` may evaluate as `double` and not provide the desired compare result.

The challenge with classify macros is that the *semantic type* may be narrower than `long double`.

---

The following uses the above ideas and  as I read the C spec is well defined and functionally correct  for all cases except the rare one: when `long double` has NaN but not the *real-floating* (often `double`) does not.

```
#include <math.h>

// compare 2 long double.  All NaN are greater than numbers.
int compare(const void *a, const void *b) {
  const long double *fa = (const long double *) a;
  const long double *fb = (const long double *) b;

  if (!isunordered(*fa, *fb)) {
    return (*fa > *fb) - (*fa < *fb);
  }

  if (!isnan(*fa)) {
    return -1;
  }
  return isnan(*fb);  // return 0 or 1
}
```

---

Note: After reading many of the good comments and learning a great deal, I am posting this self-answer as provided in [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) in addition to accepting another answer.