# qsort: Cast the comparator function itself or the parameters in the body of comparator function?

Tags: c, qsort

There are a couple of obvious ways to use `qsort`: cast in the comparator:

```
int cmp(const void *v1, const void *v2) 
{
    const double *d1 = v1, *d2 = v2;
    ⋮
}

qsort(p, n, sizeof(double), cmp);
```

or cast the comparator:

```
int cmp(const double *d1, const double *d2) 
{
    ⋮
}

qsort(p, n, sizeof(double), (int (*)(const void *, const void *))cmp);
```

I tend to use the former, more for aesthetic reasons than anything else.  Are there any technical reasons for preferring one over the other?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You should avoid the latter case because it's not valid.

For two function types to be compatible, the return types must be compatible and the corresponding parameter types must be compatible.  A `const void *` is not compatible with a `const double *` therefore the function types are not compatible.  Calling a function through an incompatible pointer type results in [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Note that just because two types may be implicitly converted doesn't mean they are **compatible**.  Taking the example of `const double *` and `const void *`, conversion between the two types can be performed without a cast, however the *representation* of the two types need not be the same.

This means that the way a `const double *` is passed to a function may be different from how a  `const void *` is passed to a function.  So by calling a function of type `int (*)(const double*, const double*)` as if it had type `int (*)(const void*, const void*)`, the parameters could be passed in an incorrect way.

While x64 and ARM systems will typically use the same representation for all pointer types, you *might* get away with doing the former, but there's still no guarantee of that.  Modern compilers will often assume undefined behavior will not happen and perform optimizations based on that fact.

The former case is the proper method as the function's signature is compatible with what the `qsort` function expects.

Comment: Interesting, thanks -- you see the latter usage all over the place, I had assumed it was conforming for that reason.

Comment: @jjg: The number of places code is seen is not an indication of its conformance to any standard or specification.

Comment: This is an excellent question and an excellent answer.  And it's worth understanding well, because although the cast-the-comparator method *looks* reasonable at first, if you think about the code the compiler is going to generate (or *has already* generated) down in `qsort`, to actually call the comparator function, you'll see that it's calling a function with two `void *` pointers, so that's what your comparator function *must* be.  (If all data pointer types are "the same" -- as of course they are all on all popular machines these days -- the wrong code will work, but it's still wrong.)

Comment: Had `void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size, int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));` been `void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size, int (*compar)();`, I suspect either form would be right.as un-prototyped object pointers are converted to `void *` (perhaps).  The important issue being how `compar` is declared.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I don't think so, as a conversion to `void *` is not among the default argument promotions.  This is why pointers passed to `printf` corresponding to the `%p` format specifier must be explicitly casted to `void *`.

Comment: @dbush Ah yes.  explicit  conversion/cast needed.

Comment: It'd be interesting if there is a real-life example where this fails, either due to unusual calling conventions or pointer representations, or aggressive optimizations.

Comment: @NateEldredge Although I've never used one, I believe it would have failed on word-addressed machines such as the PR1ME, which had 16-bit word pointers but (the equivalent of) 18-bit `char` and `void` pointers.  There's some information on this in the [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html).

Comment: @NateEldredge It would certainly have failed comparing `char`s on the early Crays, because Cray pointers addressed 64-bit words and contained additional internal fields to handle `char` data packed 8 bytes to a word.

Answer (score 12):

As an addendum, there is another strategy to call `qsort`: create an intermediary `qsort` required prototype function that calls a type-enabled comparison function.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static int double_cmp(const double *d1, const double *d2)
    { return (*d1 > *d2) - (*d2 > *d1); }

static int double_void_cmp(const void *v1, const void *v2)
    { return double_cmp(v1, v2); }

int main(void) {
    double p[] = { 2.18, 6.28, 3.14, 1.20, 2.72, 0.58, 4.67, 0.0, 1, 1.68 };
    const size_t n = sizeof p / sizeof *p;
    size_t i;
    qsort(p, n, sizeof *p, &double_void_cmp);
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) printf("%s%.2f", i ? ", " : "", p[i]);
    fputs(".\n", stdout);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Although this has its own problems, one can use `double_cmp` as a comparator for other non-`qsort` things. Also, it doesn't require any casts or explicit assignments, *per* my interpretation of [ISO 9899](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 6.3.2.3,

> A pointer to *void* may be converted to or from a pointer to any
> incomplete or object type . . . and back again.

Comment: note: the programming jargon for this technique is *thunk*, meaning an intermediate function that makes some wee adjustments so that incompatible source and destination can come together

Comment: @M.M I think that would be called a "wrapper", not a thunk. A thunk is the use of a function or closure to "suspend" evaluation of an expression, passing the code around like data to add laziness to an eager language. It is a common technique in strict functional languages. Thunks usually take no arguments and return a value of the specified type.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to *dbush* excellent answer, it should be noted that the case of an alternate comparison function with a prototype of `int cmp(const char *s1, const char *s2)`, such as `strcmp` is not as clear cut as the one in the question. The C Standard specifies that:

> **6.2.5 Types**
>
> [...] A pointer to `void` shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a pointer to a character type. Similarly, pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements. All pointers to structure types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as each other. All pointers to union types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as each other. Pointers to other types need not have the same representation or alignment requirements.

So pointers to functions with prototypes `int cmp(const void *v1, const void *v2)` and `int cmp(const char *v1, const char *v2)` are **not compatible** but the calling sequence is quite unlikely to be different even on those extremely rare targets where `int cmp(const double *v1, const double *v2)` would be problematic (early Cray systems and CPUs lacking byte addressability).

---

You do not provide the code for the comparison functions: it is a common mistake to simply return the difference of values (`*d1 - *d2`). This does not work for floating point values and neither does it for `int` values as the subtraction may overflow.

Here is an implementation for increasing order that works for all number types:

```
int cmp(const void *v1, const void *v2) {
    const int *p1 = v1, *p2 = v2;
    return (*p1 > *p2) - (*p1 < *p2);
}
```

For floating point types, special handling of NaN values may be needed:

```
// sort by increasing values, with NaN after numbers
int cmp(const void *v1, const void *v2) {
    const double *p1 = v1, *p2 = v2;
    if (isnan(*p1)) {
        return isnan(*p2) ? 0 : 1;
    } else
    if (isnan(*p2)) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return (*p1 > *p2) - (*p1 < *p2);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this `double` compare handling of `NAN` UV - like this [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48069558/2410359).  Get those `NAN`s out of the way first.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem asked in the question and should be a comment or a separate question.

Comment: @pipe: this answer is really food for thought in connexion with the question. The OP did not post the code of his comparison functions, but casual readers should learn how to write these comparison functions correctly, beyond the prototyping issue.

Comment: @chqrlie So write a blog about it or ask a question. "Food for thought" is _at best_ a comment.

Comment: @pipe: It may well be more of commentary, but a) it wouldn’t work well as a comment due to its length and inclusion of code, and b) it very clearly provides value to readers of this thread, and thus helps build off of the accepted answer. I see no reason to e.g. delete it as _not an answer_. If there is a case for discretion in reviewing answers, surely this is one such case; removing it would do a disservice to future readers.

Comment: @JeremyCaney: "this thread" has the problem that the Stack Overflow design is explicitly and intentionally not a threaded message board/forum. Comment lengths are intentionally capped to prevent this confusion. (See the relevant Meta SO discussions)

Comment: @MSalters: Perhaps. Though I’ve flagged or reviewed over 7,500 answers, and I’ve only encountered two or three “commentary answers” that add enough value that I don’t feel comfortable voting to delete. The vast majority are very clear cut.